# difference between two random effects models?

Tags: stata, random-effects-model

I am trying to understand the difference between the random effects model options I have, and I don't understand the documentation on them well enough to figure that out. They are xtlogit and melogit in stata, which both produce almost identical results if I put in the same coefficients/outcomes, but not quite identical. This is how they are described in their support function:

[melogit](https://www.stata.com/manuals/memelogit.pdf):
fits mixed-effects models for binary and binomial responses. The conditional distribution
of the response given the random effects is assumed to be Bernoulli, with success probability determined by the logistic cumulative distribution function. Option 1: Two-level logistic regression of y on x with random intercepts by lev2; Option 2: Mixed-effects model adding random coefficients for x

[xtlogit](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtlogit.pdf)
xtlogit fits random-effects, conditional fixed-effects, and population-averaged logit models for
a binary dependent variable. The probability of a positive outcome is assumed to be determined by
the logistic cumulative distribution function. Results may be reported as coefficients or odds ratios. Option description: Random-effects model of y as a function of x1, x2, and indicators for levels of categorical variable

How are these different, and what do I need to consider when thinking about if that difference matters? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without seeing the code, but I think they should yield virtually identical estimates. If you use the same starting values and the same number of quadrature points, does that make the difference go away?

Comment: This assumes you are not running a `melogit` with random slopes as well as a random intercepts and comparing to an `xtlogit` with random intercepts only.